# Debug flutter app launched by Make in VSCode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a Flutter app that is launched in the Terminal with a `Makefile` command e.g. `make run-debug env=ENV`. The make command is running `fvm flutter run --debug --flavor dev -t lib/main.dart  --dart-define ENV_VARIABLE=xxx`

I want to be able to debug this app in VSCode.

My `launch.json` is

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "my_app",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart",
      "flutterMode": "debug",
      "preLaunchTask": "run-debug"
    },
    {
      "name": "my_app (profile mode)",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart",
      "flutterMode": "profile"
    },
    {
      "name": "my_app (release mode)",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart",
      "flutterMode": "release"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the `tasks.json` is

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "run-debug",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "source ~/.zshrc && make run-debug env=dev"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I start debugging (F5), I can see it build in Xcode, then launch correctly but I the  breakpoints are not hit.

I also tried launching the Flutter DevTools debugger in Chrome but I can't see where to place breakpoint in that UI either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll need to use Attach if you want to attach the VS Code debugger to an instance of Flutter that was launched externally (otherwise it'll run its own). You can do this using the "Attach to Flutter..." commands from the palette, or using `"request": "attach"` in your launch.json. Out of interest, why do you need to launch the app from Make?